# gsub in R to standardize mixed date format in data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, date, gsub

i have a dataframe with dates in different formats.
want to first only remove `19` in the year of those that have it and use `as.POSIXlt` to convert the dates.
but the gsub isn't picking up

```
df.DOB <- c("12/11/99", "10/24/67", "8/18/13", "2/29/45", "2/28/63", "12/14/77",
            "07/25/1923", "01/07/1989", "09/02/1974")

gsub("\\/19.*", "", df.DOB)

# [1] "12/11/99" "10/24/67" "8/18/13"  "2/29/45"  "2/28/63"  "12/14/77" "07/25"  "01/07" "09/02" 

df.DOB.formatted <- as.POSIXlt(df.DOB, format = "%m/%d/%y")
df.DOB.formatted <- df.DOB.formatted - 100L
df.DOB.formatted

# [1] "1999-12-10 23:58:20 EST" "2067-10-23 23:58:20 EDT" "2013-08-17 23:58:20 EDT"
# [4] NA                        "2063-02-27 23:58:20 EST" "1977-12-13 23:58:20 EST"
# [7] "2019-07-24 23:58:20 EDT" "2019-01-06 23:58:20 EST" "2019-09-01 23:58:20 EDT"
```

would be grateful for your help

thanks

Comment: How do we know that `8/18/13` should be interpreted as `08/18/1913` and not `08/18/2013`?  There are many edge cases which you need to clarify here.

Comment: What is your final expected output? Maybe there is a better way here which does not involve `gsub` step at all.

Comment: first I'm expecting > gsub("\\/19.*","",df.DOB) 
[1] "12/11/99" "10/24/67" "8/18/13"  "2/29/45"  "2/28/63"  "12/14/77" "07/25/23"    "01/07/89"   
[9] "09/02/74"

Answer (score 2):

I added an extra entry in `df.DOB` to have 19 as date.

You can use `sub` to remove "19" which is followed by two characters.

```
df.DOB <- c("12/11/99","10/24/67","07/25/1923", "01/07/1989",
             "09/02/1974","01/19/1987")
sub('19(?=..$)', '', df.DOB, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "12/11/99" "10/24/67" "07/25/23" "01/07/89" "09/02/74" "01/19/87"
```

Comment: Yes! seem more robust!  could please explain a little bit `19(?=..$)` part?

Comment: `?=` is a positive lookahead regex which will remove 19 only if it is followed by two characters after it which are at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_replace.

```
 library(stringr)
 df.DOB <- c("12/11/99","10/24/67","8/18/13","2/29/45","2/28/63","12/14/77", 
        "07/25/1923","01/07/1989","09/02/1974")

 str_replace(df.DOB, "19", "")
 # if you have 19 in other parts
 str_replace(df.DOB, "19(?=..$)", "") # From Ronak and Darren comments
```

Another solution is that you can separate month and year and apply replacement only on year (thanks all for your comments on my answer):

```
df.DOB <- c("12/19/1999","10/24/67","8/19/13","2/29/45","2/28/63","12/14/77", 
           "07/25/1923","01/07/1989","09/02/1974")

df1 = str_split(df.DOB, "/", simplify = TRUE) 
df1[,3] = str_replace(df1[,3], "19", "")
apply(df1,1,function(d) paste(d,collapse = "/"))
```

Comment: This will also remove "19" from dates.

Comment: i see complications when day is 19th. for example df.DOB <- "09/19/1999"

Comment: `str_replace(string, pattern, "")` is equivalent to `str_remove(string, pattern)`. Maybe the latter is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Another `regex` pattern:

```
df.DOB <- c("12/11/99", "10/24/67", "07/25/1923", "01/07/1989", "09/02/1974", "01/19/1987")

sub("19(..)$", "\\1", df.DOB)

# [1] "12/11/99" "10/24/67" "07/25/23" "01/07/89" "09/02/74" "01/19/87"
```